# Check if Windows-application is run as a service

Tags: winapi

Is there a way to determine if a Windows-process is run as a service ? Is there any fixed parent-process of all the services which I can identify to assure that the process is a service-process.

Comment: possible use [*EnumServicesStatusExW*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-enumservicesstatusexw) for get all services process id and compare with known. but what sense it this ?

Comment: Some services run inside a `svchost.exe` process, but most services run as standalone processes. So, unless `scm.exe` shows up as the parent process when enumerating processes with `Process32(First|Next)()`, about all you can do is enumerate the installed services looking for the `.exe` file or process ID you are interested in.

Comment: I want to know if an application is run from commandline or as a service. EnumServicesStatusExW doesn't help because the call would be made before the EXE would be registered by the SCM.

Comment: *I want to know if an application is run from command line or as a service* - you need set special tag parameter in command (*lpBinaryPathName* ) when you register self application as service and on start - simply check command line

Answer (score 0):

if application designed for run both as service and as standalone application, the best way know how application started - use command line. when you register service with [*CreateServiceW*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicew) - pass to *lpBinaryPathName* some arguments. and then on start - check string returned by [*GetCommandLineW()*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew) - are this arguments present. if yes - you run as service, if no - as standalone application.

for example append `\n` symbol to the service binary file path :

```
WCHAR BinaryPathName[MAX_PATH + 3];
ULONG cch = GetModuleFileNameW(0, BinaryPathName + 1, _countof(BinaryPathName) - 3);
if (GetLastError() == NOERROR)
{
    BinaryPathName[0] = '\"';
    BinaryPathName[cch + 1] = '\"';
    BinaryPathName[cch + 2] = '\n';
    BinaryPathName[cch + 3] = 0;
    //CreateServiceW(.., BinaryPathName, ..);
}
```

(*`\n` selected because this symbol can not be in command line if exec application manually* )

and then in application entry point do very simply and fast check

```
if (wcschr(GetCommandLineW(), '\n'))
{
    const static SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ste[] = { { L"my_service_name", ServiceMain }, {} };
    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ste);
}
else 
{
  // run as standalone application
}
```

i think this solution is the best. however possible and others. for example we can do next check:

```
ULONG SessionId;
if (ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &SessionId) && 
    WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() == SessionId)
{
    // we not run as service;
}
```